# Rails 6: Can I create an associated record to delegate to when a new record is created but not saved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `CustomerProfile` model that is associated with `Mobile` that handles mobile number verification, sms notifications, etc…

When creating the customer profile, I would like to set the user's mobile number as if that column existed on the profile table itself. To this end, I've used `delegate`. However, the associated mobile record is not created until after the new profile is saved.

```rb
class CustomerProfile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
  has_one :mobile, autosave: true, dependent: :destroy

  delegate :number, to: :mobile, prefix: :mobile
  delegate :number=, to: :mobile, prefix: :mobile

  after_create -> { create_mobile }

  ...
end
```

So, I can't create a new customer profile and set a mobile number. I have to save the record before I set the number.

```
[1] pry(main)> profile = CustomerProfile.new
  TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  BEGIN
=> #<CustomerProfile:0x00007fb371201300 id: nil, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, user_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
[2] pry(main)> profile.mobile_number = "123"
Module::DelegationError: CustomerProfile#mobile_number= delegated to mobile.number=, but mobile is nil: #<CustomerProfile id: nil, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, user_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

From what I understand from the docs, there isn't a callback for this.

I don't think it is possible because the mobile record needs an id to point to and customer profile doesn't get one until it is saved. Is that right?

Is there a way to create an association when the model is first created without the save step?

Answer (score 0):

You can create associated objects in Rails before save.

For your `has_one` association it would look something like this

```
customer_profile = CustomerProfile.new
customer_profile.build_mobile
```

Now you can use `customer_profile` object in your form to make input field for taking mobile number or just use `customer_profile.save` to save `customer_profile` and `mobile` objects that have `has_one` relationship.